# How do I access libraries I'm adding via require, in my Node/Koa server

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa-router

I'm trying to require an external library in my Node app (Koa server). I'm adding njwt in my main server.js file `var njwt = require('njwt');`

But I can't access `njwt`, in my route handler function it gives an error saying `njwt` is undefined.

From this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5809968), it seems that using strict mode in my main server.js file makes functions and variables defined in my imported file inaccessible.

But what's the workaround?

Comment: Is the module installed in your local project?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, all you need to do is change it to: `var njwt = require('./njwt');`

This is assuming you have already done an `npm install` in the `njwt` directory.

Comment: It gives me an error, `Cannot find module './njwt'`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is how to send njwt instance to your router,
You can pass njwt instance like this,

require('./routes')(njwt);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I just ended up requiring the library in the route handler

```
const router = require('koa-router')();
router.post('/register', async function(ctx, next) {
    var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    debugger;
```

And I'm able to access the library this way (the other two methods didn't work for me).