# why is var mysql = require('mysql'); returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

EDITED:

I am working on a page that takes the information a user enters into a form and adds it to a database. I created the database with mysql. When trying to connect to my database using javascript. My code breaks on `var mysql = require('mysql');`:

I realized that this may be due to either the code being ran in a function or having the DOM related code in the function...

I tried running a simple version of the code without those elements and it works to connect to and update the database but I need to be able to pull the values from the form so I am still struggling with how to do this.

```js
function saveUserForm() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");
    var psw = document.getElementById("psw");
    var userName = document.getElementById("userName");
    var email = document.getElementById("inputText");
    alert('test');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    alert("mysql test");
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "abc123",
      database: "PBSC_Parking_DB"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
     if (err){
         throw err;
         alert("error");
     }

    var sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, UserPassword) VALUES ('"+userName+ "', '"+firstName+"','"+lastName+"','"+email+"','"+psw+"')";

      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            alert("test error");
        }
        alert("account added");
        console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
      });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Please write the thrown error in your question. Undefined of what?

Comment: how does require() work in the same code as DOM commands? missing a tag? if using a client-side require, it's usually async and needs a callback or promise to access the imported values.

Comment: it doesn't say undefined of what... it just says 'undefined' i added at image of it for clarification

Comment: i doubt the mysql module works in the browser.

Comment: the result of a variable declaration is `undefined`.

Comment: you should do `console.log(mysql)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try writing npm i mysql in the built in terminal of your ide instead of cmd and check that the mysql folder is added to your project dependencies 
or you can run npm i --g mysql to install that globally

Comment: how do I check that it's added to my project dependencies? I did already try npm install mysql -g

Comment: in the root folder of your project there is a folder called node_modules. check that folder the mysql folder should be there if its successfully installed

Answer (score 0):

`require('mysql')` is async, so it needs to be treated as a promise. For safety, I would load this outside of the function scope. The only time you would need to `require` something inside the scope of a function is for lazy loading local assets.

Comment: I tried moving it outside the function and it still doesn't work

Comment: Check this answer out, it might be what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390007/5326451

Answer (score 0):

You try to include a library with node from cmd so that's normal to give you undefined.
cause node declares values like this. so you seem to install MySQL with npm globally. so it appears with you.

[image]

that's not related to your code at all.
you need to produce bug in your code via log error or debug code!

Comment: it doesn't give an error... it just doesn't work. The alert doesn't alert on line 9 doesn't display is how i know it's breaking there.

Comment: Cause you shouldn't use **document** in the backend. it's related to DOM [front-end] .
so remove the first 8th lines from code then run the file

Comment: I don't understand without document how I can pull the values from the form... but I tried taking them out for now and it still doesn't work.