# trying to connect to TCP server using Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, tcpclient

I'm trying to connect to a server/specific port using Node.js, and I don't even get past `var net = require('net');`

I'm using Node.js v16.15.0.

`Welcome to Node.js v16.15.0.`

When I use the command above, I receive UNDEFINED. As far as I know, I've installed everything I need (including socket.io), and I'm working within the Node.js environment in iTerm.

My goal is to connect to a TCP server, receive a list of files, and then download each of them over a persistent socket. But I'm a little stuck as I can't even seem to get into the TCP server in the first place.

This is what I *think* I'm supposed to run to get in (obviously with my correct port and IP info which is omitted below).

`var HOST = 'IP';`
`var PORT = 'PORT'`
`var FILEPATH = 'myfilepathhereIwilltweakitwhenIgettothispoint';`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, I think you are trying to code NodeJS script within the NodeJS executable start in command line. You get an `UNDEFINED` because you imported the library into your variable and this assignment does have any value, so it is `UNDEFINED`. You can read more about this in this subject : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389977/node-js-require-returns-undefined-always)

But what we usually do in NodeJS development is creating a file, let's call it `index.js`. Inside that file we are writing our code, let's say :

```js
const net = require('net');
const client = net.createConnection({ port: 8124 }, () => {
  // 'connect' listener.
  console.log('connected to server!');
  client.write('world!\r\n');
});
client.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
  client.end();
});
client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('disconnected from server');
});
```

Code sample from [NodeJS Documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/net.html#netcreateconnection).

Then we want to run our code by using the command line like this : `node path/to/index.js`.

Hope it helps !